# Slow performance on mysql query in Rails app

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, performance

I have three tables in mysql for a rails app:

- stories(id, title, summary, hotness) => has 217754 records
- tags(id, name) => has 25123 records
- taggings(story_id, tag_id) => has 800751

This is log from Rails:

Story Load (14300.8ms)

```
SELECT `stories`.*
FROM `stories` INNER JOIN
     `taggings`
     ON `taggings`.`story_id` = `stories`.`id` INNER JOIN
     `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id`
WHERE (tags.id = 3141)
ORDER BY hotness
LIMIT 26 OFFSET 0
```

It takes more than 14 seconds. I'm sure all indexes in stories, tags and taggings are okay.
Another thing that I have to say is hotness always is changing.

Is this about scalability of MySql?

PS:
Explain result => https://gist.github.com/iCEAGE/8622705

Comment: What is the output of EXPLAIN to that query? If you do a SELECT count(*) for the query do you get reasonable results?

Comment: This is not about the scalability of MySQL.  This is either about your indexes being wrong or a *lot* of data matching that particular tag.  Please post the indexes that you have on the table.

Comment: @scraatz EXPLAIN output added to PS. SELECT count(*) has a reasonable result, it's around 0.3s

Comment: The explain indicates that your indexes are correct and mysql needs no time to execute the query (3 rows in set (0.02 sec)). Seems to be a problem in your Rails code that loads the stories. I don't know about Rails, but I have seen problems in  object-relational mapping frameworks (like Hibernate) where all relations of an object are loaded when you load an object. Could this be your problem?

Comment: @scraatz That's not about Rails because it also happens from mysql command

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query because you are not using anything from the `tags` table:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM `stories` s INNER JOIN
     `taggings` t
     ON t.`story_id` = s
WHERE t.id = 3141
ORDER BY s.hotness
LIMIT 26 OFFSET 0;
```

If this doesn't help, how large is this?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `stories` s INNER JOIN
     `taggings` t
     ON t.`story_id` = s
WHERE t.id = 3141;
```